# How does Tyrion Lannister send this Lord to the wall? (A Clash Of Kings spoilers)

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

After having read twice the scene in *A Clash Of Kings*, where Tyrion Lannister sends:

> Lord Janos Slynt to join the Night's watch.

I'm a little confused. I understand somewhat *why* Tyrion does it, I'm just a little confused as to how he managed to pull it off without being cut short by his sister.

> Cersei wanted Slynt in command of the City watch, did he really spirit
>  Slynt away without her noticing? Wouldn't Cersei have taken measures
>  to get Slynt back?

I'm discussing the books here, although having rewatched the scene in the TV show where it happened, they seem similar enough as for it not to matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Theoretically Cersei as regent has ultimate authority in the realm and should have been able to maintain control.

However, the reality of the situation is that Tywin, not Cersei, is in charge of the Lannister faction due to his direct control over Lannister bannermen and armies, his financial power (the throne's treasury is empty), and his status as Cersei and Tyrion's father.

Tyrion was sent to be the new Hand by Tywin to fix the problems that Cersei has caused, and so when acting as "Hand of the king" Tyrion is actually acting on the authority of Tywin. This is why Tyrion can force Cersei to make these concessions. Even though nominally Cersei has the authority to prevent Tyrion from acting, she cannot afford to anger Tywin any more than she already has.

Answer (score 8):

The position of [Hand of the King](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hand_of_the_King) is the highest position in the Seven Kingdoms other than the King. The Hand otherwise runs the realm when the King can not or will not. Cersei would not have been able to stop his order even if she tried as Tyrion's authority at the time superseded hers.

Comment: Does the Hand have more authority than the Regent who [`is in charge of ruling the realm when the current king is underage or incapable of ruling due to injury or illness`](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Regent)? I agree that had Joffrey been ruling in his own right, and Cersei simply being Queen, that Tyrion would have had more authority. But I am not sure if this is true as she was Queen Regent at this point.

Comment: As evidenced by Ned Stark's head being on a spike, Joffrey was ruling in his own right.  That's the whole reason why Tywin sent Tyrion - Joffrey was not under the control of Cersei.

Answer (score 8):

At this point, Tyrion has control of the City Watch, as he has appointed Ser Jacelyn Bywater as the new commander of the City Watch ([ACOK chapter 8](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Clash_of_Kings-Chapter_8)). Cersei does not have the strength on the ground in King's Landing to oppose the decision.

It is possible she could try to get Slynt sent back while he is in transit, but that would require Lannister men to enforce her orders over those of Tyrion, who is acting as Hand in place of Tywin Lannister. Given Tywin's reputation, there are few who would dare be seen as opposing him.

The only mention of her response is in [Chapter 17 of ACOK](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Clash_of_Kings-Chapter_17), where she seems resigned to his decision:

> "Brother," she called out, not warmly. The queen had not been pleased by the way he'd dealt with Janos Slynt.